# What does 'not enough x observations' imply in R?

Tags: r, testing, statistics

I'm trying to run a t-test in R Studio and I keep coming back with this error -->

```
Error in t.test.default(x = subset(mydata$InfMort, subset = mydata$SubSahCountryvariable == : not enough 'x' observations
```

Here's the code -->

```
with(mydata, 
  t.test(x = subset(mydata$InfMort, subset = mydata$SubSahCountryvariable == 1), 
         y = subset(mydata$InfMort, subset = mydata$ArabCountryvariable == 1), 
         alternative = "two.sided"))
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? I'm a beginner level in R.

Comment: Try `with(mydata, t.test(x = InfMort[SubSahCountryvariable == 1],  y = InfMort[ArabCountryvariable == 1]))` it is possible that the one of them have different `length` compared to other

Comment: It's hard to know without having any of your data and thereby being able to run your code. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with.

Comment: If you just calculate the `x` value, i.e. `subset(mydata$InfMort, subset = mydata$SubSahCountryvariable == 1)`, what do you get?  Similarly, what do you get for `y`?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have less than the minimum number of observations in the first group, which is 2 observations. For example:

```
> t.test(c(1), c(3,4))
Error in t.test.default(c(1), c(3, 4)) : not enough 'x' observations
```